# How to run java 8 applets with java7u60 plugin?

Tags: java, windows, security, applet, local

I'm on clean install Windows 8.1 and I'm trying to run the java 8 example applets provided by oracle.

I've:

- Downloaded jdk8 x64 (which installed the jre8 also)
- Tried to run the applets, but then had to follow the link to install the latest plugin (java7u60) ( I didn't install the 7u60 jre, just the recommended plugin).

  > - It is verified on the java verification page
  > - I now have JDK 8, Java 8, and Java 7u60 as installed programs. Which I think is what is causing the problem.
- Tried again and got them blocked by security settings

  > - Went to control panel>java control panel and changed to medium setting
- Tried again and got block by security settings again, they are being reverted as soon as I try to run an applet.

  > - Found https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javacpl.xml and tried it, but they still revert when I try to run an applet.
  > - Tried to run jre8/bin/javacp.exe directly as administrator, didn't help either.

Any help on what my next step is? I can't find a java 8 plugin for chrome or firefox so how are they suppose to run the example java 8 applets without it?

Thanks

Comment: Browsers are, by default, set to block the Java plug-in due to security issues. At least it seems like that now-a-days.

Comment: So chrome is reverting the java control panel security settings? So no one can run applets?

Comment: I stopped using chrome, but I know I was trying to run some applets that were part of a book and I couldn't ever get fox to do it.

Comment: Yeah same thing is happening in Firefox

Comment: Answering my question: I was not using a x64 browser. So I uninstalled the x64 java software and installed 32bit jdk8 and 32bit java 8 examples.

Shouldn't there be a check to see if the browser is 32bit before it changes the security settings?